# Копирование страницы

Tags: php, http

Имеется простая страница с таблицей

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#C0C0C0" cellpadding="0" 
width="100%"><tbody>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#c0c0c0"><p align="center"><strong>№ Карты</strong></p></td>
<td bgcolor="#c0c0c0"><p align="center"><strong>Пользователь</strong></p> 
</td>
<td bgcolor="#c0c0c0"><p align="center"><strong>Баланс</strong></p></td>
</p></td>
</tr><tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff">001641</td>
<td>Иванов Иван Иванович</td>
<td><p align="right">100,00</p></td>
</tr><tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff">001679</td>
<td>Антонов Артём Анатольевич</td>
<td><p align="right">200,00</p></td>
</tr><tr>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

требуется средствами php скопировать эту таблицу к себе на страницу.

есть еще один нюанс, доступ к исходной таблицы осуществляется через HTTP Basis аутентификацию.

просьба помочь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$host_api = "http://site.ru";
$param = 1;

// авторизация
$curl = curl_init($host_api);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);       
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);       
// get запрос
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "$host_api/script.php?param=$param");       
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);

print $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Если таюлица на чужом сайте, то делайте все через функцию get_file_contents (вот статья на хабре https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/72702/ ) насчёт аутентификации, не знаю, но в документации по php есть раздел "базовая http аутентификация", попробуйте поискать там